# Accessing the Variables issue when using methods and functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

```
 var generateSearchObject = function() {
            var searchObj = {
                /*value assigned to variable "check" should be here like "fileName":check*/
            };
            return searchObj;
        };

var s =  {
renderBreadCrumbs: function(breadCrumbs, state, node) {
                $(breadCrumbs).each(function(index, value) {
                    //var check = "Something";
                });
                        //return check
            }
 }
```

I tried my best to resolve this issue and reaching out to Community. I would like to access the variable which is there in $(breadCrumbs) in searchObj. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please try and explaining further what it is you're trying to do? An example would be helpful.

Comment: I want to access the value inside the $(breadCrumbs) and use it in searchObj. I wouls like to add a vlaue like seachObj.fileName : "THE VALUE WE GET FROM BREADCRUMB"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998797/create-breadcrumbs-dynamically-on-client-side-using-javascript - This might help.